# read.zoo always prints out results - why?

Tags: r, zoo

I am using `read.zoo` to read tab-separated datafiles into a zoo time series. I have the following code:

```
z <- read.zoo("poolBL03GD04_842_WMO_03862.tts", index=2:5, FUN = conv)
```

As far as I understand, this is assigning the result of the `read.zoo` function to the `z` variable, but it prints out the entire result of `read.zoo` as well. Why is this, and how can I stop it?

**Updated with reproducible example:**

```
library(chron)
library(zoo)

conv <- function(y,m,d,t) {
  date_str <- paste(m,"/", d, "/", y, " ", sep="")
  time_str <- paste(t, ":00", sep="")
  print(date_str)
  print(time_str)
  chron(date_str, time_str)
}

zz <- textConnection("51645  2000 04 11  00:00  2367.35   80.9   12.5
51645  2000 04 11  01:00  2370.38   88.8   13.7
51645  2000 04 11  02:00  2357.50   80.6   12.5
51645  2000 04 11  03:00  2360.38   87.2   13.5
51645  2000 04 11  04:00  2354.70   84.0   12.9
51645  2000 04 11  05:00  2345.91   79.3   12.2")
z <- read.zoo(zz, index=2:5, FUN = conv, header=F)
```

This is even more frustrating when trying to use `read.zoo` from within a function.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It is your punishment for not providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I was going to provide a reproducible example, but the data that I've got isn't allowed to be shared at all. I'll try and make some stuff up in the same format.

Comment: Reproducible example is up now - sorry guys.

Comment: it's not quite reproducible without the `conv` function.

Comment: Should be fully reproducible now, I think.

Comment: As I thought... blame the `conv` function, not zoo.  You might owe zoo an apology too. ;)

Comment: I talked to zoo earlier and the zoo is pissed at always taking the blame. Don't anger the zoo.

Comment: Also note that you can eliminate `textConnection` like this: `Lines <- "51645  2000 04 11  00:00  2367.35   80.9   12.5\n 
51645  2000 04 11  01:00  2370.38   88.8   13.7"; read.zoo(text = Lines, ...whatever...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment the `print` lines in your `conv` function.

```
conv <- function(y,m,d,t) {
  date_str <- paste(m,"/", d, "/", y, " ", sep="")
  time_str <- paste(t, ":00", sep="")
#  print(date_str)
#  print(time_str)
  chron(date_str, time_str)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about zoo, but it's worth noting that you can use capture.output to force anything to send it's output to a variable.